# Could somebody explain how to get the Curious, Inquisitive and Socratic badges?

Tags: support, questions, badges

I don't understand very well how it is possible to ask a question on 5 separate days or more. I can ask a question in 5 minutes or less.

Also very confused about what the phrase "positive question record" means. Does it mean that the questions must have votes up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To earn the Curious badge you must:

> Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintain a positive question record

You would need to ask at least 5 questions to earn this badge, each on different days. The questions have to be "well-received" which means they have a positive score and are on-topic (not on hold or closed as Glorfindel pointed out). A positive question record means you have more positively scored questions than negatively scored questions (so questions that aren't well-received could make it harder for you to earn this badge).

So, one way to earn this badge is to spend more than 5 minutes writing your questions! There is a lot of advice here on meta for writing questions that are likely to be well-received:

[Please, everyone... details. Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/)
[How can I write a better title for my ELL question?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2630/)
[So, you found a sentence or phrase... (Why you should cite your source)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1084/)

One of the answers in the "Details, please" discussion has a good template for questions:

1. Begin with an introduction, explaining where this word or phrase was found
2. Explain why this word or phrase seems confusing
3. Share the results of what was found when research was performed
4. End with a clearly defined question that explains what is being asked about

Comment: Additional information: well-received also means it may not be closed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that negative score, closure, and deletion *all* individually count as a poorly-received question, so a -2 closed deleted question is the same as three -1s.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I don't know all the details - I think it's safe to say that if you want the badges, you should strive to write consistently high quality on-topic questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got a vote down for one of my questions, but don't know exactly why. Maybe it was too simple? Also I still have quite a bunch of questions about the site, but I don't want to post too much of them. Probably I could ask them in chat?... I would be very, very glad if I find a well-informed person with whom I could talk about this site.

Comment: @Alex89 You certainly can ask in [chat] - many of the people that are in chat regularly have a really good understanding of the site and are happy to help. There is also an FAQ here https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/ that has a lot of good information about how StackExchange works. There's also nothing wrong with asking here (if you've searched first). If you have a question about something, it's very likely someone else will have the same question.